# Bean type not found when using Spring aspect and java config

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-3, wicket-6

I added an aspect to a working Spring+Wicket application to log thrown exceptions, and now I get the following error whenever I load the Report page:

```
ERROR | 2013-12-09 08:42:06,149 | qtp1559334851-16 | DefaultExceptionMapper:123 - Unexpected error occurred
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public org.jonblack.ReportPage() throws java.lang.Exception'. An exception has been thrown during construction!
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:194)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:67)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: bean of type [org.jonblack.ReportController] not found
    at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.getBeanNameOfClass(AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.java:236)
    at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.getBeanName(AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.java:179)
    ...
```

I'm using java configuration for the project, so there is no `applicationContext.xml`. All configuration is done via annotations, the bulk of which are in `AppConfig.java`.

All the code for my application is shown below. I've left out the HTML templates and HomePage as they aren't integral to the problem.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.jonblack</groupId>
  <artifactId>sw-p2</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!-- TODO project name  -->
  <name>sw-p2</name>
  <description></description>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <wicket.version>6.11.0</wicket.version>
    <jetty.version>7.6.3.v20120416</jetty.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <!--  WICKET DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
      <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
      <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
      <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
      <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
      <artifactId>wicketstuff-annotation</artifactId>
      <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
      <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
      <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- aspectj -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- LOGGING DEPENDENCIES - LOG4J -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  JUNIT DEPENDENCY FOR TESTING -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--  JETTY DEPENDENCIES FOR TESTING  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
      <testResource>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <directory>src/test/java</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
          <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
              <port>8080</port>
              <maxIdleTime>3600000</maxIdleTime>
            </connector>
            <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
              <port>8443</port>
              <maxIdleTime>3600000</maxIdleTime>
              <keystore>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/keystore</keystore>
              <password>wicket</password>
              <keyPassword>wicket</keyPassword>
            </connector>
          </connectors>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
package org.jonblack;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
//import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.jonblack")
@EnableAsync
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy()
public class AppConfig {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConfig.class);

  @Bean
  public ReportController reportController() {
    log.info("Getting ReportController");
    return new ReportController();
  }

  @Bean
  public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    pool.setCorePoolSize(5);
    pool.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    pool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    return pool;
  }

  @Bean
  public ExceptionLoggingAspect exceptionLoggingAspect() {
    return new ExceptionLoggingAspect();
  }

  @Bean
  public AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator annotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator() {
    AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator aop = new AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator();
    return aop;
  }
}
```

**ExceptionLoggingAspect.java**

```
package org.jonblack;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Aspect
@Component
public class ExceptionLoggingAspect {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionLoggingAspect.class);

  @AfterThrowing(pointcut="execution(* org.jonblack.ReportController.getReportData(..))", throwing="ex")
  public void afterThrowing(Throwable ex) {
    LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
  }

}
```

**ReportController.java**

```
package org.jonblack;


import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
//import org.springframework.core.task.AsyncTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncResult;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class ReportController {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportController.class);

  @Autowired
  private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

  @Async
  public Future<String> getReportData() throws Exception {
    log.info("Entered into getReportData()");

    try {
      log.info("Throwing an exception");
      throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      log.error("In catch block: {}", ex.getMessage());
    }

    final Future<String> result = taskExecutor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
      @Override
      public String call() throws Exception {
        return "not a fancy result";
      }
    });

    log.info("Returning from getReportData()");
    return result;
  }
}
```

**ReportPage.java**

```
package org.jonblack;

import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringBean;
import org.wicketstuff.annotation.mount.MountPath;


@MountPath("report")
public class ReportPage extends WebPage {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportPage.class);

  @SpringBean
  ReportController reportController;

  public ReportPage() throws Exception {
    log.info("Starting ReportPage");

    reportController.getReportData();
  }
}
```

**WicketApplication.java**

```
package org.jonblack;

import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication;
import org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringComponentInjector;
import org.wicketstuff.annotation.scan.AnnotatedMountScanner;


public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication
{
  @Override
  public Class<? extends WebPage> getHomePage()
  {
    return HomePage.class;
  }

  @Override
  public void init()
  {
    super.init();

    // Spring
    getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(
        new SpringComponentInjector(this));

    // Annotation-driven page mounting
    new AnnotatedMountScanner().scanPackage("org.jonblack").mount(this);
  }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  version="2.5">

  <display-name>sw-p2</display-name>

  <!-- Configuration loading -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
      org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jonblack.AppConfig</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Spring -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Wicket -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>wicket.sw-p2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
      <param-value>org.jonblack.WicketApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>wicket.sw-p2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I've followed the [Spring reference for Aspects](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop) but it's very thin on the ground when it comes to java configurations (and I do find the reference to be quite hard to follow).

I've also done the obligatory [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/) search and found only references to XML configurations.

On stackoverflow itself I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077346/java-illegalstateexception-bean-type-not-found) which explains the same problem, but the cause in that instance was an incorrect annotation and incorrectly named applicationContext.xml file: neither of these helped resolve my situation. I tried using `@Autowired` instead of `@SpringBean`, and got the same `NullPointerException`. Given that the linked post resolved it without this change, I assume this isn't the right path to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your configuration.

```
@Bean
public AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator annotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator() {
    AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator aop = new AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator();
    return aop;
 }
```

This bean leads to creation of a proxy of a proxy. The `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation already registers an `AutoProxyCreator` and due to the existence of multiple, different instances, this will lead to proxy duplication.

Next to that the additional declaration of your aspect might lead to 2 aspects being instantiated.

```
@Bean
public ExceptionLoggingAspect exceptionLoggingAspect() {
  return new ExceptionLoggingAspect();
}
```

Your `@Aspect` is also an `@Component` and as such will be detected by the `@ComponentScan` functionality.

Basically removing both beans should fix your problem.

```
public Future<String> getReportData() throws Exception {
    log.info("Entered into getReportData()");

    try {
      log.info("Throwing an exception");
      throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
    } catch(Exception ex) { // This catch blocks swallows the exception
      log.error("In catch block: {}", ex.getMessage()); 
    }
}
```

Next to your configuration problems, you also have a problem with your code. Basically your aspect is useless. You have a try/catch block in your code which swallows the `Exception`. This swallowing leads to a situation where your aspect never sees the exception and will never trigger. From your aspects point of view the exception never happened.

Either don't catch and simply let the `Exception` bubble up the stack or rethrow the `Exception`.

Comment: It runs without error now, thanks; however, my aspect doesn't work. When the exception is thrown in the `ReportController`, I do not see the log message given in the aspect (I do see the log messages in the surrounding try...catch block).

Comment: And why should the aspect see your error? You are catching it and swallowing it. So the exception never bubbles up the call stack so it is impossible for the aspect to see the exception.

Comment: I was under the impression that `@AfterThrowing` would get intercepted regardless of a catch block. There are some tutorials out there that show the try...catch block to illustrate what happens, which I now see is incorrect.